# Gunicorn worker killed

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I am running a flask application (rest api) with gunicorn and I am seeing almost every 30 seconds a batch of `[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14727)`. 
My settings are the following:

```
gunicorn --worker-class gevent \
         --timeout 30 --graceful-timeout 20
         --max-requests-jitter 2000 --max-requests 1500
         -w 50
         --log-level DEBUG --capture-output
         --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 run:app
```

I saw previous post that had said to throw more RAM at this but from the looks of it:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 513926
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 131071
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1550298
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

The Heap is unlimited and stack size is slightly over 8Mb.

### Log sample

```
+0000] [26657] [DEBUG] GET /timer
[2017-01-21 14:07:30 +0000] [26657] [DEBUG] GET /timer
[2017-01-21 14:07:33 +0000] [26657] [DEBUG] GET /timer
[2017-01-21 14:07:33 +0000] [26652] [DEBUG] GET /timer
10.193.80.149 - - [21/Jan/2017:14:07:34 +0000] "GET /timer?id=699ec59eccd3fb929b3dd7707e542ed15acd4181:6f136b54-2cb5-42ef-9def-f69caaba57ef HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "-"
10.193.80.147 - - [21/Jan/2017:14:07:35 +0000] "GET /timer?id=e7963c53603ed9249b0aa557d8a64cea89fb0bf4:6f136b54-2cb5-42ef-9def-f69caaba57ef HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "-"
10.193.80.150 - - [21/Jan/2017:14:07:35 +0000] "GET /timer?id=4b750805193fb4d00c3ce1465c266ed932a24e55:6f136b54-2cb5-42ef-9def-f69caaba57ef HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "-"
[2017-01-21 14:07:37 +0000] [26657] [DEBUG] GET /timer
[2017-01-21 14:07:37 +0000] [26657] [DEBUG] GET /timer
[2017-01-21 14:07:37 +0000] [26635] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:27202)
[2017-01-21 14:07:37 +0000] [26635] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:27205)
```

What I noticed was only a handful of workers are always doing the work `26657`, `26652` `26651` everything else just seems to be giving me the `Worker timeout`

Answer (score 0):

You have some requests which take longer than 30 seconds to finish, that's why they are killed. Either:

- tune your code so each request is done within less than 30 seconds (that might also be due to slow database or other dependencies)
- check if your host is short on resources, this could be due to CPU or RAM. Tuning your machine by putting more RAM into the machine only helps if each of your unicorn processes eats a lot of RAM and the machine starts swapping. Try e.g. `top` to check if CPU or RAM are saturated.
- increase the timeout by changing the `--timeout 30` to a higher number. That's the worst idea really, as you don't solve your underlying problem that your flask app responds slowly to incoming requests. Plus killing long running requests often helps the other flask threads to not run into resource problems as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will try increasing the timeout, there might some fine tuning in the code I could do. Since this specific server is only being hit with endpoints that communicate with kafka and my settings might be stopping me from finishing on time. I'll increase the timeout although I think I was seeing the same issue with a timeout of `100`. The code shouldn't take that long to run, the endpoint gets called and I put a message into a kafka topic and thats it. It shouldn't be resource intensive or time consuming

Comment: there are definitely some threads which take very long. Did you have a look into the flask logfiles? Aren't these killed threads logged somehow?

Comment: I am not seeing any stacktraces, only timeouts. I have updated my question with some sample from the logs